# Universal links doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

This is my `apple-app-site-association` file:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "paths": [
                    "*",
                    "\/doubanapp\/*",
                    "\/authorHome"
                ],
                "appID": "KV99XUUJ3U.com.moer.MoerFinance"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I already set Xcode Associated Domains, this is my screenshot:

[image: image description here]

I use https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ test my domains,but get error:

> Error no apps with domain entitlements The entitlement data used to
>   verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released
>   version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

If my app must be released then wait for 48 hours?

Comment: is your `apple-app-site-association` file on a https server? The certificate must NOT be self signed. I had this struggle just a week ago. You could try reinstalling your app on your phone via lightning cable and then look into the logs of that device. That's how I found out, that the server certificate was not valid. In particular, search for "apple-app-site-association" in your log

Comment: My certificate is self signed.I try to buy a legal certificate,hope it useful. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to buy one, you can get can a usable free one at sites like https://www.startssl.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement that your app be live in the App Store for Universal Links to work.

However, looking at `https://moer.jiemian.com/apple-app-site-association` and `https://moer.cn/apple-app-site-association`, both are serving invalid SSL certificates. iOS will reject these, which breaks Universal Links.

I'll put in a shameless plug here for [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), in case you're just looking for simple deep linking and don't want to deal with these set up details.

Comment: It is like to my certificate is self signed,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the self-signed cert issue, have you tried adding `?mode=developer` to the URL in your entitlements (e.g. `applinks:mydomain.com?mode=developer`) for the Associated Domains?

This is the format for the domain when you're using an untrusted cert:

`<service>:<fully qualified domain>?mode=<alternate mode>`

with

`<alternate mode>` set to `developer` as in my example above

Docs say:

> developer
>
> Specifies that only devices in developer mode can access the domain. In this mode, you can use any valid SSL certificate on your web server, including a certificate the system doesn’t trust. Make sure you don’t expose your users to security issues, such as man-in-the-middle attacks. As an added precaution, only apps signed with a development profile can use developer mode, and users must opt in on any device they use.

Here's the reference documentation from Apple - scroll to the bottom of the page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains