# iOS Universal Link: Do I have to publish my app in order to test Universal Link?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-universal-links

Here is my main question: Do I have to publish my app that has the Universal Link support changes to make it work or I can test the Universal Link in local simulator without publishing the app version containing the support for Universal Link?

I've been trying to set up universal link by following the apple guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

I've uploaded the aasa file into the server my.site.com:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "****.com.my.app",
                "paths": ["*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "***.com.my.app2",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The entitlement file is create in project with item:

```
applinks:my.site.com
```

The AppDelegate has function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

I try it by running the app in simulator. I create a calendar event with the web link in the note. But it redirects me to Safari every time the link is tapped.

Am I missing any step if any?

Thanks in advance;)

Comment: No, you don't need to publish your app to test Universal Links. I think you missed this: application(_:continue:restorationHandler:). There's a link in the guide you're using.

Comment: @Don: Sorry that's a typo... I use this function in AppDelegate: ```func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool```

Comment: @Don I'm getting the same error as in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018565/universal-links-doesnt-work but my SSL cert seems valid according the browser ... ...

Comment: did you check in the web server logs if the device fetches the file ?

Comment: @Bastian The server logs show that the device is fetching the file.

Comment: After many investigations, it turns out the root cause is that: when debugging the app in simulator, the app doesn't include entitlement file. So my solution is: I archive the app, distribute the app for development, which generates an .ipa file. With that ipa file installed in device, I can see that the entitlement can be detected

Comment: Please don’t edit the question to include the answer. Answer your own question as an actual answer and accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

After many investigations, it turns out the root cause is that: when debugging the app in simulator, the app doesn't include entitlement file. So my solution is: I archive the app, distribute the app for development, which generates an .ipa file. With that ipa file installed in device, I can see that the entitlement can be detected

Comment: What if i run app with release mode? I've tried it and UL doesn't work